# how to install requirements in a sagemaker processing step/job within a sagemaker pipeline?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I have setting up a processing job in a sagemaker pipeline, and my project has following files

```
projectA
  - run.py
  - requirements.txt
```

I have some dependencies that i need to install before i run my script , which are listed in requirements.txt. I'm not sure , how can i set up the processing step , such that it installs the requirements before it runs my script.

any thoughts?

```
from sagemaker.processing import ScriptProcessor
from sagemaker.workflow.steps import ProcessingStep

script_processor = ScriptProcessor(
    instance_type='ml.t3.medium', 
    instance_count=1, 
     ...
    command = ['python']
)

processing_step = ProcessingStep(
  name='p_step',
  processor= script_processor,
  code = './run.py',
  inputs = [
  ...]
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my knowledge of SageMaker Pipelines and SageMaker Processing Jobs, there are 2 ways to manage dependencies - either you create an image and specify it in the `image_uri` when defining the `ScriptProcessor` object or you install them during the job runtime. Here is how to do the second approach.

I provide the following example (which uses the `SKLearnProcessor` class for the job):

1.Define the processing job:

```py
sklearn_processor = SKLearnProcessor(
        framework_version="1.2-1",
        instance_type=instance_type_preprocessing.default_value,
        instance_count=instance_count.default_value,
        role=role_pipeline,
        sagemaker_session=pipeline_session,
)
```

2. Define the job step arguments in the following:

```py
step_args = sklearn_processor.run(
        inputs=[
            ProcessingInput(
                input_name="raw-data",
                source=input_data,
                destination="/opt/ml/processing/input",
            ),
            ProcessingInput(
                input_name="preprocessor",
                source=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "my_job/requirements/"),
                destination="/opt/ml/processing/input/code/requirements/",
            ),
        outputs=[
            ProcessingOutput(
                output_name="train",
                source="/opt/ml/processing/artifacts/ml_modelling/train",
                destination=Join(
                    on="/",
                    values=[
                        ...
                    ],
                ),
            ),
        ],
        code=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "my_job/run.py"),
    )
```

The second item in inputs, should point out to the requirements.txt file, which I recommended you bundle everything together in a my_job directory.

3. Then, in your entry point script for the job, put the following in the before making the imports of the dependencies you required:

```py
import traceback
import os
import sys
import subprocess

subprocess.check_call(
    [
       sys.executable,
       "-m",
       "pip",
       "install",
       "-r",
       "/opt/ml/processing/input/code/requirements/requirements.txt",
    ]
)
```

4.Proceed to add the import statements of your dependencies as normal.
5. Verify your project structure is as follows:

```
my_project
 - my_job/
     - requirements/
          - requirements.txt
     - run.py
```

**Note on this approach: Only do it if you trust what is in the requirements.txt file and you don't want to build the image and push it to ECR.**

Do let me know if this solve your issue and/or you have questions on the code.